# Angular i18n ICU select supporting untranslated values

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I use ICU select to translate bind data in html template. How can I force angular to display data not being translated?

HTML template including ICU select:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let mode of deviceModes" [value]="mode.id" i18n>
    {mode.name, select, mode {mode}}
</mat-option>
```

XLIFF file:

```
<source>{VAR_SELECT, select, mode {mode} }</source>
<target state="final">{VAR_SELECT, select, press_me {Press Me} guard_me {Guard Me} disarmed {Disarmed} active {Active} suspended {Suspended} broken_or_stolen {Broken or stolen} }</target>
```

It works fine but if mode.name contains a new value that is not translated in XLIFF file, it is currently not displayed in html. I need to show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use other on select as default value to get the untranslated value try:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let mode of deviceModes" [value]="mode.id" i18n>
{mode.name, select, mode {mode} other { {{mode.name}} } }
```